# Show the value of an item at a position in a Material Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I have a List of Array String that I populate the values in a Material Dialog. When I click on an item in the dialog, I want to get the item at that position and set the value to a TextView. Unfortunately no matter the item I choose I still get the last value set to the TextView.

My code:

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(DetailProfileActivity.this)
    .title(R.string.id_types_title)
    .items(set)
    .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(0, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
            idType = which;
            switch (idType){
                case 0:
                    txtIdType.setText("Voters");
                case 1:
                    txtIdType.setText("Passport");
                case 2:
                    txtIdType.setText("DriversLicense");
            }

            return true;
        }
    })
    .positiveText(R.string.choose)
    .show();
```

Comment: @R2R my issue is that i only get the value "DriversLicense" set to my TextView even if i choose different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this   `onSelection()` giving the string result you can use directly

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(DetailProfileActivity.this)
            .title(R.string.id_types_title)
            .items(set)
            .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(0, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                    txtIdType.setText(text);
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .positiveText(R.string.choose)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. dont know what i was thinking.